# Buying used Xeons from China or South Korea

Tags: hardware, xeon

I'm not sure why so many of the Xeons selling on Ebay are coming from China and South Korea. Prices are extremely reasonable (delivery especially given the distance) and I'm wondering if these are safe or a known scam?

Comment: Got a link to them?

Comment: Strange question,  buy them from a official channel and not on ebay ?

Comment: @Chopper3 sure - https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_nkw=xeon+x5670&_sop=15

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the link - this has nothing to do with them being from China or elsewhere, the reason they're cheap is they're 7 year old models. Specifically 'Westmere-EP' chips using socket LGA 1366, they're essentially worthless, the CPU in your phone's probably more capable.

Comment: They are indeed, but that doesn't address why so many are coming from China, HK and South Korea (there's usually a few more from Korea) and it also doesn't address why they sell for less than from UK sellers, or why the delivery is so cheap (they surely can't send these around the world for £3?).

Comment: Presumably they do a lot of scrap processing there rather than in the UK, I know a lot of the PCB recycling happens in that general part of the world. As for shipping, well I'm in the UK too and have found that when I order stuff from China etc. that it's started to come really quickly and quite cheaply - even compared to a few years ago - maybe there's a small-package-shipping deal that they've set up? Either way I doubt there's anything dodgy about these CPUs, they're just old, used and someone has a million of them in a box somewhere.

Comment: You're probably right. I know Ebay has a pretty bad reputation in recent years for sellers, but I think buyer protection is still supposed to be pretty good, so should be safe enough I guess. Thanks for your replies!